# Problems forwarding zone to another DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, forwarding

I have a authorative DNS server at 83.248.21.18 which are authorative for the domain "finahemgoteborg.se".
Now my registrar is requiring me to have 2 DNS servers for the domain, so I would now want the machine 85.228.103.141 just forward all incoming queries for "finahemgoteborg.se" to the 83.248.21.18 server.

In the 85.228.103.141 BIND server, I have the following config:

```
zone "finahemgoteborg.se" in {
type forward;
forwarders {83.248.21.18;};
};
```

But the problem is that 85.228.103.141 is still responding with "REFUSED" when querying it for example www.finahemgoteborg.se A record.

How can I fix it. I do NOT want to set up a master/slave situation, just one nameserver that forwards to a another.

**Edit** 
The Rest of named.conf:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";  
  version "none";
  allow-recursion {"none";};
  minimal-responses no;
};

zone "sebn.us.to" in{
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/sebn.us.to";
};

zone "ns1sebn.us.to" in{
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/sebn.us.to";
};

zone "ns2sebn.us.to" in{
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/sebn.us.to";
};

zone "finahemgoteborg.se" in{
type forward;
forwarders {83.248.21.18;};
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the fragment you've posted. What does the rest of `named.conf` look like?

Comment: Seems that changing the line allow-recursion {"none";}; into allow-recursion {"any";}; fixes the problem, but does it not open a security hole allowing anyone to use the DNS server to do lookup to another hosts than those that has a valid zone-line? Also, how can I do for the server to always answer authoratively for all queries?

Comment: Try adding "forward only;". I don't think it is possible to force it to claim to be authoritative for the zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved in a pretty non-technocal way:
Switching to a registrar that does not require 2 DNS servers. Found one that gladly accepted one single nameserver on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Is there possibly an ACL on either server that is preventing the forwarding?

Have you restarted both servers (or at least done `rndc reload`)

Comment: Glen: No, theres no ACL. The 83.248.21.18 is allowing queries fron anywhere so there should not be problem. Yep I have reloaded both servers. (/etc/init.d/bind9 restart)

Answer (score 0):

"type forward;" is wrong. What you need is master/slave DNS relationship.